# Picture rotates on Preview Screen when launching the camera with ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() on Android API 26

Tags: android, android-camera

I am launching the device's camera with `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()` to allow the user to take a picture.
When the user takes a picture and the picture is previewed to them right away, it gets rotated:

[image: camera]

[image: picture preview]

**While previewing the picture, the result of `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()` hasn't returned to my app yet, so my app had zero interaction with it.** The resulting picture will only be returned to my app when the user clicks on the check button.

Is it an Android or Emulator bug or is it working as intended?

I tested the same thing on an emulator API 33 and on my personal physical device (API 28), and that behavior doesn't happen.